# how to use CircularProgressBar in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I need a function to show a progress ring in dialog when query data in a database, the traditional progress bar is not good for me because I don't know exactly how long the waiting time will last.
So I installed CircularProgressBar from Nuget to show the progress ring.
but there is no example code, I don't know how to use it.
Did anyone use this control before?
my questions are:
1. how can I drag this control to a toolbox, now I cannot see this CircularProgressBar control in the toolbox of visual studio 2015 even though I already see this reference in a project;
2. how to invoke it or write some show/close code to show it and close it when I need it in a dialog.
thanks,

Comment: individual controls aren't opened or closed; you can show or hide them instead (see `Visible` property, just like for any control). I haven't used this control, but I would expect it to work just like the regular `ProgressBar` control. So, maybe you should try there. Asking such a wide range of questions, and without any code showing what you've tried so far, is really too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look at [this article](https://www.csharpens.com/c-sharp/circular-progress-bar-in-c-sharp-windows-form-applications-23/). the sample code in that article is :

```
#region Includes
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#endregion

#region CircularProgressBar

public class CircularProgressBar : Control
{

    #region Enums

    public enum _ProgressShape
    {
        Round,
        Flat
    }

    #endregion
    #region Variables

    private long _Value;
    private long _Maximum = 100;
    private Color _ProgressColor1 = Color.FromArgb(92, 92, 92);
    private Color _ProgressColor2 = Color.FromArgb(92, 92, 92);
    private _ProgressShape ProgressShapeVal;

    #endregion
    #region Custom Properties

    public long Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set
        {
            if (value > _Maximum)
                value = _Maximum;
            _Value = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public long Maximum
    {
        get { return _Maximum; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 1)
                value = 1;
            _Maximum = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Color ProgressColor1
    {
        get { return _ProgressColor1; }
        set
        {
            _ProgressColor1 = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Color ProgressColor2
    {
        get { return _ProgressColor2; }
        set
        {
            _ProgressColor2 = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public _ProgressShape ProgressShape
    {
        get { return ProgressShapeVal; }
        set
        {
            ProgressShapeVal = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #region EventArgs

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        SetStandardSize();
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        SetStandardSize();
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs p)
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(p);
    }

    #endregion

    public CircularProgressBar()
    {
        Size = new Size(130, 130);
        Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 15);
        MinimumSize = new Size(100, 100);
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    private void SetStandardSize()
    {
        int _Size = Math.Max(Width, Height);
        Size = new Size(_Size, _Size);
    }

    public void Increment(int Val)
    {
        this._Value += Val;
        Invalidate();
    }

    public void Decrement(int Val)
    {
        this._Value -= Val;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);
                using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, this._ProgressColor1, this._ProgressColor2, LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal))
                {
                    using (Pen pen = new Pen(brush, 14f))
                    {
                        switch (this.ProgressShapeVal)
                        {
                            case _ProgressShape.Round:
                                pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
                                pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                                break;

                            case _ProgressShape.Flat:
                                pen.StartCap = LineCap.Flat;
                                pen.EndCap = LineCap.Flat;
                                break;
                        }
                        graphics.DrawArc(pen, 0x12, 0x12, (this.Width - 0x23) - 2, (this.Height - 0x23) - 2, -90, (int)Math.Round((double)((360.0 / ((double)this._Maximum)) * this._Value)));
                    }
                }
                using (LinearGradientBrush brush2 = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, Color.FromArgb(0x34, 0x34, 0x34), Color.FromArgb(0x34, 0x34, 0x34), LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
                {
                    graphics.FillEllipse(brush2, 0x18, 0x18, (this.Width - 0x30) - 1, (this.Height - 0x30) - 1);
                }
                SizeF MS = graphics.MeasureString(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32((100 / _Maximum) * _Value)), Font);
                graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32((100 / _Maximum) * _Value)), Font, Brushes.White, Convert.ToInt32(Width / 2 - MS.Width / 2), Convert.ToInt32(Height / 2 - MS.Height / 2));
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
                graphics.Dispose();
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}

#endregion
```

then you can Use this control any where you want to show progressbar.
**UPDATE**

How to Use:

1. Open your application where you want to use Circular Progress Bar.
2. Select & Drop CircularProgressBar.cs file on your project in solution explorer.

[image]

3. Just Compile your application & you will see a circularprogressbar option in your toolbox.

[image]
4. Use & give values to it like you give to the default progress bar. It will works.

Comment: this is just the source code of CircularProgressBar , not the sample code. I need the example like in a winform dialog. create a CircularProgressBar  and invoke its related functions to show and hide it, etc.

Comment: Just drag and drop this control to your form! and use it like regular progress bar!!

Comment: my questions are: 1. how can I drag this control to a toolbox, now I cannot see this CircularProgressBar control in the toolbox of visual studio 2015 even though I already see this reference in a project;

Comment: actually I installed the CircularProgressBar from Nuget, I think this is the correct way to invoke a dll or control. I cannot paste my Nuget installed list here but I can see this control in reference

Answer (score 1):

If you set maximum to 3, the percent value printed is 99%
so, modify and put a little check to reach 100% in last value set

```
                int percentvalue = Convert.ToInt32((100 / _Maximum) * _Value);
                // here, check if value == maximum
                if (_Value == _Maximum) percentvalue = 100;

                //Desenhe o texto de progresso:
                Brush FontColor = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
                SizeF MS = graphics.MeasureString(Convert.ToString(percentvalue) + "%", Font);
                graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(percentvalue) +"%", Font, FontColor, Convert.ToInt32(Width / 2 - MS.Width / 2), Convert.ToInt32(Height / 2 - MS.Height / 2));
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
```